# Cannot enter credentials for Github in Xcode

Tags: xcode, github

I want to push my project to my Github account. I am able to connect with my account and create a new repository on Github. But when I then want to push to that remote for the first time, I cannot seem to be able to provide the system with my credentials.
Specifically, I cannot change the username to anything; it in the textfield just says `git` and I can't fill in my real username.

Xcode Version is the currently latest 9.2, if that matters.

Any hint or help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out: I had chosen to clone using SSH, and Xcode automatically used me private key I had stored in `~/.ssh/`. I even had provided my passphrase for the private key under Accounts in Xcode.
The thing that was missing on the **Github** side was the corresponding public key. After having provided my Github account with that, pushing works like a charm.
Hope this helps someone some time, cheers.